# How to show content when website is loaded from exteral url

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

On a SvelteKit website I'm trying to load an age checker when the website is loaded for the first time. once they say "yes" an animation starts and you can interact with the website. But when navigating through the website the age checker shows for each page.

I've tried using the afterNavigate svetekit tool but on any navigation change even inside of the website domain it fires the age checker again. Where I only wanted it to fire when someone comes from outside of the website domain.

I'm looking for a way to only fire when a user comes from outside of the website domain, and while navigating the domain pages the age checker doesn't fire.

```
<script>
    import { afterNavigate } from '$app/navigation';
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';

    // hide by default
    let visible = false;

    let duration;

    afterNavigate(({ from }) => {
        // only animate if the navigation came from outside the page
        duration = from === null ? 200 : 0;
        // toggle visbility in any case
        visible = true;
    });
</script>

<div class="hero_animation">
    {#if visible}
    <h1 in:fade={{ duration }}>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
    {/if}
    
</div>
```